# $0 \times a \cong 0$ without exponentiation

Tags: category-theory

I know how to prove $0 \times a \cong 0$ in categories admitting exponentiation (and initial objects, of course). But does this hold for categories that don't have exponentiation?

I don't have enough examples in my mental categories library to give a counter-example, nor have I managed to prove that $0 \times a \cong 0$ based on just the notion of products.

Comment: You mean $0\times a\cong 0$?

Comment: Oh, that's a really great typo here on my side! Thanks, corrected!

Comment: The dual to this would be the coproduct of a terminal object with an arbitrary object is terminal. But that's not true in the category of sets, so your statement is false in $\textbf{Set}^{\textbf{op}}$.